# How do I use a pinch gesture to open another viewController?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I want to be able to open viewController B by pinching the screen on viewController A. 
Ideally I would like to be able to do this in Storyboard.

Any help/direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how far you can go in Storyboard directly, but the basic is you add a `UIGestureRecogniser` object and connect it to your view control and configure it for a pinch gesture. Then when the `UIGestureRecogniser` receives a pinch event it'll trigger the action you've hooked it up to, and you can trigger a `segue` event which you can also configure within the Storyboard, or you can push the new `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, so far I've used     UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];  than   - (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(id)sender
{
    //((UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender).scale;
    
    if (((UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender).scale > 1.0) {
        AustraliaViewController *aust = [[AustraliaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Australia" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aust animated:YES];
    }
} doesn't like it

Comment: Which part doesn't it like? If you can get it recognising the gesture then you're half way there.

Comment: -[CTSViewController handlePinchGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed630d0'     When I connect the button to the other Viewcontroller Do I choose push/modal/custom? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: it is recognising the pinch gesture, but it's throwing the exception

Comment: Could you put the code into a Gist (https://gist.github.com/) just to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77b5001542c5c31a9694   I think this is the procedure.. Not entirely sure..

Comment: Interesting, I just implemented it in a blank project and it doesn't throw any unrecognised selector issues. Try doing a clean build and going from there.

Comment: Tried in a brand new project still no luck.. the console is showing the gesture activity. Am I trying to instantiate the AustraliaViewController in a wrong way? I've also tried this [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Australia"];  Doesn't work..

Comment: It should just push it onto the navigation stack, so I'm not 100% sure why it wouldn't. Might be worth opening it as a new question.